# Spring web service client XwsSecurityInterceptor afterCompletion exception

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jakarta-ee, spring-ws

I've implemented a **Spring Web Service Server** and **Client** with the configuration enclosed below.

I have opted to use `simplePasswordSecurity` mechanism and *both sides* have been fitted to handle this. So far I can send my request from client to server, server will process the request and send the response back.

In my terminal log, I can see that client receives the response but out of nowhere I get this exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor.afterCompletion(Lorg/springframework/ws/context/MessageContext;Ljava/lang/Exception;)V
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.triggerAfterCompletion(WebServiceTemplate.java:806)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:615)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
```

....

**Any ideas why I get this exception?**

## Server

### spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="FinancialService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="schemaCollection">
        <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
            <property name="inline" value="true" />
            <property name="xsds">
                <list>
                    <value>schemas/FinancialServiceOperations.xsd</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="portTypeName" value="FinancialService" />
    <property name="serviceName" value="FinancialService" />
    <property name="locationUri" value="/endpoints" />
</bean>

<sws:interceptors>
    <bean id="authenticationInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="policyConfiguration" value="/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml" />
        <property name="callbackHandlers">
            <list>
                <bean id="passwordValidationHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler">          
                    <property name="users">  
                        <props>  
                            <prop key="myUser">myPassword</prop>
                        </props>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</sws:interceptors>
```

### spring-security.xml

```
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config" dumpMessages="true">  
    <xwss:RequireUsernameToken passwordDigestRequired="false" nonceRequired="false"/>  
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

### pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

## Client

### spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11" />
    </property>
</bean>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" context-path="com.example.domain.service.financial.stub" />

<bean id="financialWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:8080/financial/FinancialService.wsdl" />
    <property name="messageSender" ref="xwsSecurityMessageSender" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="xwsSecurityInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="xwsSecurityMessageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender" />
<bean id="xwsSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="policyConfiguration" value="/WEB-INF/spring-ws-security.xml" />
    <property name="callbackHandlers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="xwsSecurityCallbackHandler" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="xwsSecurityCallbackHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.MockValidationCallbackHandler" />
```

### spring-security.xml

```
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config" dumpMessages="true">
     <xwss:UsernameToken name="myUser" password="myPassword" digestPassword="false" useNonce="false"/>
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

### pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

## Terminal Log

```
INFO: ==== Sending Message Start ====
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-140733907019228719200">
<wsse:Username>willapweb</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">****</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:OnlinePaymentFormRequest xmlns:ns2="http://com/example/ws">
<ns2:serial>c3hqvk9dejps923m01qrpqrh6f</ns2:serial>
<ns2:amount>200000</ns2:amount>
</ns2:OnlinePaymentFormRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
==== Sending Message End  ====

INFO: ==== Received Message Start ====
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-140733907019228719200">
<wsse:Username>willapweb</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">****</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:OnlinePaymentFormRequest xmlns:ns2="http://com/example/ws">
<ns2:serial>c3hqvk9dejps923m01qrpqrh6f</ns2:serial>
<ns2:amount>200000</ns2:amount>
</ns2:OnlinePaymentFormRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
==== Received Message End  ====

INFO: ==== Sending Message Start ====
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:OnlinePaymentFormResponse xmlns:ns2="http://com/example/ws">
<ns2:message>{"form":"&lt;form action='https://bank.om/Payment.aspx' method='post' id='bank-form'&gt;&lt;input type='hidden' name='Amount' value='200000'/&gt;&lt;input type='hidden' name='MID' value='12'/&gt;&lt;input type='hidden' name='ResNum' value='c3hqvk9dejps923m01qrpqrh6f'/&gt;&lt;input type='hidden' name='RedirectURL' value='http://130.185.73.133/payment/verification'/&gt;&lt;\/form&gt;","successful":true}</ns2:message>
</ns2:OnlinePaymentFormResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
==== Sending Message End  ====

INFO: ==== Received Message Start ====
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:OnlinePaymentFormResponse xmlns:ns2="http://com/example/ws">
<ns2:message>{"form":"&lt;form action='https://bank.com/Payment.aspx' method='post' id='bank-form'&gt;&lt;input type='hidden' name='Amount' value='200000'/&gt;&lt;input type='hidden' name='MID' value='12'/&gt;&lt;input type='hidden' name='ResNum' value='c3hqvk9dejps923m01qrpqrh6f'/&gt;&lt;input type='hidden' name='RedirectURL' value='http://130.185.73.133/payment/verification'/&gt;&lt;\/form&gt;","successful":true}</ns2:message>
</ns2:OnlinePaymentFormResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
==== Received Message End  ====
```

Comment: Have you thought of checking your JAR's version (esp. spring ws core vs. spring ws security ?).

Comment: @GPI I just added pom.xml relevant dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely have incompatible JARs in your classpath.

**AbstractMethodError**

`AbstractMethodError` is a runtime error that is thrown by the JVM when a method that should exist, actually does not.

This should not happen in your own code : the compiler prevents you from calling methods that do not exist.

However, when using external JARs (that depend upon other external JARs), the compiler can not warn you.

Say I have A-1.0.jar, which contains class A, that has a method `doStuffV1()`.
Then, A-2.0.jar, which contains an update to the class A, which adds another method `doStuffV2()`.
Finally, say I have B-2.0.jar, which is compiled with A-2.0.jar, with class B that extends A.

In you project, if you import B-2.0.jar only, and you use class B and call `doStuffV2`, the compiler will not complain : you are using a class that's working.

But if, at runtime, you throw in your classpath A-1.0.jar and B-2.0.jar, when your code executes, you will get `AbstractMethodError` : what existed when B-2.0.jar was compiled, does not exist at runtime. This is a crash.

**Applied to Spring WS Jars 2.0.0 to 2.2.0**

In Spring WS, if you look at Spring WS 2.0.0 Javadoc, which your are referencing, you can see here (http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/index.html) the afterCompletion signature :

> public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext,
> Object endpoint,
> Exception ex)

But if you look at the 2.2.0 api (http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/api/) the same method does exist, only with a different signature. To the Java compiler and runtime, this is NOT the same method :

> public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext,
> Exception ex)
> throws WebServiceClientException

**Informations from your stacktrace**

Your stack trace indicates that the runtime, from the WSTemplate class, tries to call the later version (see the first line).

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ...XwsSecurityInterceptor.afterCompletion(Lorg/springframework/ws/context/MessageContext;Ljava/lang/Exception;)V
> at org...WebServiceTemplate.triggerAfterCompletion(WebServiceTemplate.java:806)

Which suggests to me that

1. you have a Spring-WS-Core (WebServiceTemplate.class) that is a 2.2.0 version
2. with a Spring WS Security (XwsSecurityInterceptor) which is a 2.1.0 version (or something in between).

That is not compatible. You should keep both versions in sync.

EDIT : with your POM, this seems confirmed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you have suggested I changed both spring-ws-core and spring-ws-security to 2.0.0
In addition It was necessary to change name of context-path property of jaxb2-marshaller to 'contextPath'
Thanks again for your response.

Comment: This was a life saver answer ! Thank you so much for this answer !!!!!!!